# Excel Analysis ToolPak Add-in Removal

Tags: excel, vba, add-in

I installed the 'Add-In Analysis ToolPak' in Excel.

My VBE has changed to look like this:

[image: Project Explorer]

How can remove the Add-In and restore my VBE interface especially Project Explorer to the interface I'm used to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VBE contains the code modules for all installed Add-Ins.

Analysis Toolpak ships with Excel, it should be safe and nothing to worry about.

If you really want to remove it you can do so from Developer | AddIns and then uncheck to remove:

[image]

Comment: Thank you excel is back as it was away from this utter ugliness!